# Indexing with loops in python

Tags: python, loops, indexing

The question asks to write a function that takes in some unordered list and from that unordered list pull any sublist that is ordered. Example [5, 2, 1, 3, 4] would become [1,3,4]. My issue is in indexing, I want a way to express that if the current iteration is greater than the one before it, I want to add it. However, the problem that my code runs into is that it compares the first and last of an item.

For my code: [5, 2, 1, 3, 4] => [5,1,3,4]

```
def numIncreasing(lst):
    ans=[]
    for index in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[index]>=lst[index-1]:
            ans.append(lst[index])
        elif lst[index]<lst[index-1] and lst[index]<lst[index+1]:
            ans.append(lst[index])
        else:
            continue

    return ans
```

edit: fixed the code not recognizing the start of the pattern

Comment: Your indentation causes a syntax error.

Comment: It is also not clear what the behavior you expect is. You say "any sublist that is ordered." What if a list has multiple ordered sublists? E.g., `[5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8]`?

Comment: It is also unclear what you expect to happen in the case when there is *no* sorted sublist of length greater than 1. (I am assuming sorted sublists of length 1 are not of interest, of course, but please correct me if that assumption is wrong.) And what about the empty list containing no elements whatsoever?

Comment: Sublists must be greater than one and [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 9]

Comment: @barskyn Do you want the largest sublist? It seems like you do.

Comment: @barskyn *Why* that sublist? Because it's the largest? Because it's the first? Some other reason? Also, do lists have to be *contiguous* or can the sublist be split by other elements? And you didn't answer my question about the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that finds the largest ordered sublist:

```
def increasing2(lst):
    length = len(lst)

    for size in range(length, 1, -1):
        for start in range(0, length - size + 1):
            curr = lst[start:start+size]
            if all(x <= y for x, y in zip(curr, curr[1:])):
                return curr

    return None
```

Which behaves as follows:

```
>>> increasing2([5, 2, 1, 3, 4])
[1, 3, 4]
```

**Logic of approach:**

- Loop over all sublists in reversed order, so the largest sublists come before the smaller sublists:

  ```
  [5, 2, 1, 3, 4]
  [5, 2, 1, 3]
  [2, 1, 3, 4]
  [5, 2, 1]
  [2, 1, 3]
  [1, 3, 4]
  [5, 2]
  [2, 1]
  [1, 3]
  [3, 4]
  ```
- If the current list is sorted, return it. Otherwise keep going through all the sub lists in order from largest to smallest length. This ensures that you get the largest sublist first. The algorithm also only considers sublists of length 2 or greater.

Comment: A few thoughts: We could just overwrite old candidates and if the remaining length is lower than the candidate you could return already.

Comment: @AntonvBR But you still need to check all possible sorted sublists, since this algorithm generates sub lists from smallest to largest length. The largest sorted list could very well be at the last iteration. I apologise If I misunderstood you.

Comment: @AntonvBR I came up with a much better way. Loop backwards instead, so that you visit the largest sublists before the smaller ones. Then exit the loop on the first sorted sublist.

Comment: yep, this looks better. At first I thought you went through many false candidates.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for the largest. It asks for "any sublist that is ordered."

Comment: @RoadRunner Why would it be silly? We have no idea what the OP's requirements are. And it sounds like the OP is doing homework, anyway, so the requirements may be extremely arbitrary.

Comment: @jpmc26 Generating all possible sorted sublists then picking a random one is an acceptable solution in either case. I've included that.

Comment: @RoadRunner It is not clear that the OP is using the word "any" in a strict, technical sense. We should wait for clarification from the OP rather than make guesses. If you don't want to delete your answer in the mean time, then you should clarify that it may not meet the OP's requirements in the event that the list contains multiple ordered sublists.